# r: converting matrix.csr to matrix. Error in as.vector(data)

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, libsvm

This is a quick question and answer as I wasted about an hour on this error

I was trying to convert a sprse matrix to a regular matrix before running a PCA.

```
rawm1=read.matrix.csr(".\\rjsmall1.libsvm")
str(rawm1)
sparse=rawm1$x
str(sparse)
sparseMatrix=as.matrix(sparse)
```

I got the following error

> Error in as.vector(data) : 
>     no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you need to use library library(SparseM).

```
as.matrix
```

is a standard r function, but it doesn't convert matrix.csr. The function in SparseM does.